# Blender - Trying to export a cloth simulation to Collada file

Tags: animation, simulation

I'm using an avatar and a skirt as .blend files and trying to create an animation as a cloth simulation (I followed this tutorial - http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-325838.html) with them on Blender, in which the avatar puts her skirt on. Now I'm trying to export the animation as a Collada (.dae) file and use WebGL (three.js) to render the animation. But the Collada file seems to not be working, since the browser (Safari) does not display the animation. How can I export this cloth simulation to a Collada file properly?

Comment: Skeletal animations using the three.js json format, for which there is an exporter for blender, at least works. I'm not sure if you can export shape key animations / morphs directly .. at least it works to export an .obj per shape and then use the commandline converter tool to create a three.js json from those.

Are you sure you want to use Collada?

Are you trying to use shapes / morph targets?

Comment: I haven't created any shape keys. There's a keyframe for every frame that I created from the cloth simulation (using that tutorial...). I tried do export my .blend file as an .obj file, but I don't know how to convert it to Collada or JSON file. Do you know how? I am having issues using the Blender JSON exporter (three.js). I'm using Blender 2.75, I don't know if the version is incompatible with the JSON exporter. I have found a Blender WebGL exporter on internet, but it does not work with Blender 2.6+, so I guess the same applies to the JSON exporter.

Comment: Just a guess, because I have seen many working tutorials on internet that show how to export animation from Blender to JSON and I think they used older versions of Blender. Anyways, JSON exporter it's not working for me.

Comment: The Blender Three.JS JSON export works with current versions of Blender and supports skeletal animations at least. Didn't get to check yet what kind of keyframes you have.

Comment: Hmm...I am still having issues coding the script (javascript). Do you know how to create the script? I don't know exactly what kind of material (there are few options) or object (Mesh, MorphAnimMesh or SkinnedMesh)  I have to use with the three.js library (http://threejs.org/docs/). I have tried simple animations like moving a cube over a plane and still the browser was not displaying the animation at all (It was showing a black screen).

Comment: Besides, I once got the JSON exporter to work on Autodesk 3ds max, but the file didn't contain any animation, just a cube on a plane and I created simple animations  (x, y and z rotations) on HTML file with three.js. When I was trying to animate the cube on 3ds max, I used the three.js exporter (ThreeJSAnimationExporter.ms script) but that didn't work, still got a black screen.